# How can I use a class property index to assign a variable?

Tags: class, delphi, properties

I have created a class:

```
type
      TShape = class
      private
        FHeight: Integer;
        FWidth: Integer;
        FDepth: Integer;

      public
        constructor CreateShape(AHeight: Integer; AWidth: Integer; ADepth: Integer);

        property height: Integer index 0 read FHeight write FHeight;
        property width: Integer index 1 read FWidth write FWidth;
        property depth: Integer index 2 read FDepth write FDepth;

      end;
```

.

```
constructor TShape.CreateShape(AHeight: Integer; AWidth: Integer;
  ADepth: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FHeight := AHeight;
  FWidth := AWidth;
  FDepth := ADepth;
end;
```

And currently I assign the values by using the name of the property to assign a variable:

```
cube := TShape.CreateShape(5, 5, 5);

height1 := cube.FHeight;
width1 := cube.FWidth;
depth1 := cube.FDepth;
```

But how do I use the index instead of the name to assign a property, so `height1 := cube.FHeight` would instead be `height1 := cube[0]`?

Comment: Notice that in your final code block, you write `height1 := cube.FHeight;` but should probably write `height1 := cube.Height;`. You want to use the public property, not the private field. The private field can only be accessed from within the class (natural) and within the same unit as the class (somewhat less natural).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how [`index` specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Index_Specifiers) work. They allow you to use a *single* getter or setter function for *several* properties:

```
TTest = class
private
  function GetColor(AIndex: Integer): TColor;
public
  property BackgroundColor: TColor index 0 read GetColor;
  property ForegroundColor: TColor index 1 read GetColor;
end;

// ...

function TTest.GetColor(AIndex: Integer): TColor;
begin
  case AIndex of
    0:
      Result := clRed; // background colour
    1:
      Result := clBlue; // foreground colour
  else
    Result := clBlack;
  end;
end;
```

Hence, it can only be used with getter and setter functions; you cannot use fields.

You seem to be interested in something different, an [array property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Array_Properties), which is in addition `default`. An array property is a property that is an array to the object's user (like `Memo1.Lines[4]`). Hence, it is *a **single** property* which is an array.

In your case, you could add a public property

```
property Dimensions[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetDimension;
```

where the private getter function

```
function GetDimension(Index: Integer): Integer;
```

is defined as

```
function TShape.GetDimension(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  case Index of
    0:
      Result := FHeight;
    1:
      Result := FWidth;
    2:
      Result := FDepth;
  else
    Result := 0; // or raise an exception
  end;
end;
```

This would still use your `FHeight`, `FWidth`, and `FDepth` fields to store the data under the hood.

Alternatively, you could store the data in a static or dynamic array of integers. *Then* you could create indexed properties `Width`, `Height`, and `Depth` and use the same getter function as for the array property:

```
type
  TShape = class
  private
    FDimensions: array[0..2] of Integer;
    function GetDimension(Index: Integer): Integer;
  public
    constructor CreateShape(AHeight: Integer; AWidth: Integer; ADepth: Integer);

    property Height: Integer index 0 read GetDimension;
    property Width: Integer index 1 read GetDimension;
    property Depth: Integer index 2 read GetDimension;

    property Dimensions[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetDimension;

  end;

// ...

{ TShape }

constructor TShape.CreateShape(AHeight, AWidth, ADepth: Integer);
begin
  FDimensions[0] := AHeight;
  FDimensions[1] := AWidth;
  FDimensions[2] := ADepth;
end;

function TShape.GetDimension(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if InRange(Index, Low(FDimensions), High(FDimensions)) then
    Result := FDimensions[Index]
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid dimension index: %d', [Index]);
end;
```

Now you can access `MyShape.Height`, `MyShape.Width`, and `MyShape.Depth`, as well as `MyShape.Dimensions[0]`, `MyShape.Dimensions[1]`, and `MyShape.Dimensions[2]`.

If you mark the array property as `default`,

```
property Dimensions[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetDimension; default;
```

you can also write `MyShape[0]`, `MyShape[1]`, and `MyShape[2]`.

**Note:** For simplicity, my examples above only use getters. But setters work as well.